# Не обновляются данные в таблице после выполнения функции как рекурсии

Tags: r

Есть таблица данных, из одного столбца. Обхожу его с помощью рекурсии. В функции изменяю данные таблицы. Во время выполнения данные меняются, увидел это через print, однако после завершения выполнения данные в таблице не сохраняются.

[image: Вот таблица с данными]

Код:

```
data$Fx <- c(0)              # создание столбца для значений F(x)
data$Flag <- c(FALSE)        # столбец для проверки вставки
data$V1 <- sort(data$V1)

MPM <- function (n, N, START, END) {
  ln = END - START + 1

  if (ln%%2 == 0) {
    leftX = ln/2
    rightX = leftX+1
    if (data$Flag[leftX])
      return()

    data$Fx[leftX] <- n
    data$Fx[rightX] <- n
    data$Flag[leftX] = TRUE
    data$Flag[rightX] = TRUE

    if (ln/2 >= START)
      MPM(n-0.5/2^N, N+1, START, ln/2)
    if (ln/2+1 <= END)
      MPM(n+0.5/2^N, N+1, ln/2 + 1, END)

  } else {
    md = ln %/% 2 + 1
    if (data$Fx[md])
      return()
    data$Fx[md] <- n
    data$Flag[md] = TRUE

    if (ln != 1)
    {
      if (ln%/%2 >= START)
        MPM(n-0.5/2^N, N+1, START, ln%/%2)
      if (ln%/%2 + 2 <= END)
        MPM(n+0.5/2^N, N+1, ln%/%2 + 2, END)
    }
  }
}
MPM(0.5, 1, 1, 3)
View(data)
```

R сегодня только начал изучать. Пробую его для выполнения лаб.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при каждом вызове функции создаётся новое уникальное *окружение* (*environment*).

глобальные переменные доступны из функции для чтения. при попытке же записи создаётся локальная копия переменной. которая уничтожается после завершения работы функции.

чтобы записать из функции в глобальную переменную, надо использовать «специальный» оператор присвоения — `<<-` вместо `<-` (или его псевдонима — `=`). в случае присвоения «направо» — `->>` вместо `->`.

---

иллюстрация:

```
> x <- 1
> y <- 1
> f <- function() {
  x <- x + 1
  y <<- y + 1
  cat( paste( "изнутри функции: x=", x, "y=", y, "\n" ) )
}
> f()
изнутри функции: x= 2 y= 2
> x; y
[1] 1
[1] 2
```

---

подробнее, например, здесь: [R Environment and Scope](https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/environment-scope/)